# QustomDialogBuilder can't find item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-dialog

I need to change the appearence of my dialogs so I decided to use [QustomDialog](https://github.com/danoz73/QustomDialog).

I'm using a custom layout via setCustomView, but when i handle onClick of PositiveButton I can't find any element of my layout.

The layout consist in a EditText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setServer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/server_url" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The Listener is:

```
QustomDialogBuilder builder = new QustomDialogBuilder(this);
/* Some customization */
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String url = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.setServer)).getText().toString();
                    if (Utilities.isUrl(url)) {
                        PreferenceHelper.setRestUrl(getApplicationContext(), url);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid URL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    }
                }
            });
```

But when i press "OK" i get `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the `findViewById` method is looking in the wrong layout (in the activity layout instead of the dialog).

You can try to create a final variable with the Dialog when it is shown:

```
final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
```

And then use it in the findViewById:

```
String url = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setServer)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: I've found the same solution debugging the code a few moments ago!
Thanks!!